# Catch any event which is doing HTTP request with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have my web site running some third party app which is doing some HTTP request to inject the data. I want to know if it is possible to catch any HTTP request which is initialized from my page, and how to catch it if it is possible?

I want to catch that with JavaScript, because I need to show on my page some hints about HTTP request.

Comment: This is really a browser level feature I would argue.

Comment: not realy... I think i know how to do that, it is nothing special. I just want to know the correct way to do that, I'm not expert in javascript , so I hope somebody can tell me the proper answer, if not I'm anyways able to do that somehow, don't worry, be happy

Comment: I think it's only possible to catch ajax requests:http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

Comment: Not JavaScript, but; Developer Tools > Network Tab. You may also have some luck wrapping _XMLHttpRequest_ with a logger.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I want to catch that with javascript, because i need to show on my page some hints about http request.

You can wrap [*XMLHttpRequest*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) in a function which logs the [*caller*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) before returning a real *XMLHttpRequest*.

```
(function () { // scope saves you from infinite loops / loss of __xhr
    var __xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest; // back up
    function XMLHttpRequest() { // wrap
        console.log(
            XMLHttpRequest.caller || arguments.caller || 'caller not supported'
        );
        return new __xhr;
    }
    window.XMLHttpRequest = XMLHttpRequest; // shadow
}());

function foo() { // example
    var bar = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
foo(); // invoke

/* console logs
function foo() { // example
    var bar = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
*/
```

---

The constructor can be retrieved by

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest(); // function doing this gets logged
window.XMLHttpRequest = x.constructor; // normality restored
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think this won't work for fetch api requests.

Comment: @EdwardChopuryan you're right, this won't work for fetch, which became available ~2015 (2 yrs after this answer). However, the same methodology *does* work, you just need to shadow `window.fetch` instead

Comment: @EdwardChopuryan Might also be worth pointing out that in modern dev tools, if you view the sources tab you can set breakpoints on all fetch + xhr requests and inspect that way, which requires no code editing

Comment: Agreed. I wonder is there a another way to intercept both type of request on sort of deeper level?